# WebView to open links in website

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to make a android app to load a website using `WebView` but the problem is that in the website I have different links. The problem is that I want to open some links in an external browser and some in the same window.

For example if the link ends with ".html" to open in the same window but the others to open in external window. What should I insert in the else branch of the following code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView myWebView;
String url = "url";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    // Configure related browser settings
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    // Configure the client to use when opening URLs
    // Load the initial URL
    myWebView.loadUrl("url");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // Api < 24
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && url.endsWith(".html")) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method was deprecated in API level 24.

```
boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)
```

for Api > 24 you can use

```
boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view,WebResourceRequest request)
```

and Here's an example for using the two methods in an app

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
// Api < 24
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && url.endsWith(".html")) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                }
            }
// Api > 24
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (request.getUrl().toString() != null && request.getUrl().toString().endsWith(".html")) {
                    view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                    return true;
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,request.getUrl()));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

Comment: It says shouldOverrideUrlLoading not used? plus when compiling it gives errors

Comment: I made some changes in the code and now its compiling correctly . When i test the app when i open a link with .html in end it opens but when i try to open other links it crashes like .jpg or sth else

Comment: I tried links end with .jpg and they working with me !. try the edited code above or post your code to check it.

Comment: i updated my code in the description above can you please check mine please

Comment: Actually It is working perfectly with me for .html and .jpg also. can you post the error when it crashes please ?

Comment: Sorry i cant since my computer can't support the device manager so i build the apk then install them on my phone